# How to get ModelState Errors at runtime using Key added by ModeState.AddModelError( key,value)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-validation, server-side-validation, addmodelerror

I have added Model error from controller using

if( model property not selected)
{
`ModelState.AddModelError("SelectionRequired","Please select atleast one value");`
}

This error I am adding at many places in that same method but ultimately I want to show to user only one such message out of the ModelState errors collection.

For that purpose before returning to view I have to remove all similar messages except one.

How can i remove this messages using **"SelectionRequired"** i.e. key and not using "Please select atleast one value".This "SelectionRequired" is not a model property name is just a key we want to use.

I checked ModelState.Keys collection at runtime I don't see the "SelectionRequired" at all in those collection and also not even in ModelState.Values collection. Then where does this key **"SelectionRequired"* goes ? and how to select errors based on it ?

is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
var error = ModelState["SelectionRequired"].Errors.First();
ModelState["SelectionRequired"].Errors.Clear();
ModelState["SelectionRequired"].Errors.Add(error);
```